# How do I extend my navbar banner below my navbar row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, bootstrap-5, banner, graphical-logo

I'm rebuilding a new website and upgrading from Bootstrap 3.3 to Bootstrap 5.  I'm re-creating the look and feel of the navbar seen [here](https://www.ogm.utah.gov/coal/index.php).  I've gotten very close but am having trouble with the banner.  I can't figure out how to get the banner to extend below the navbar and still fit within the container class.

Here's a chunk of their code that displays the image I'm also opting to use:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <script src="http://www.utah.gov/nav/fluidheader.js" type="text/javascript" class="utahgov"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="root/images/purpleLogo.png" class="purpleLogo" />
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">HOME<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li ><a href="https://www.ogm.utah.gov/index.php">Division Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/index.php">Oil and Gas Program Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/forms.php">FORMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/statistics.php">STATISTICS</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://oilgas.ogm.utah.gov/oilgasweb/live-data-search/lds-files/files-main.xhtml">WELL FILES</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">QUICK REFERENCES<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceBonding.php">Well Bonding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceDrillingPermits.php">Drilling Permits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceDrillingWell.php">Drilling a Well</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceOperatorChanges.php">Operator Changes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceReporting.php">Reporting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It looks like all they're doing is putting the image in the same container as the navbar items and the banner is automatically spilling out of the navbar.  So far, I have the navbar elements in their own row. Then I divided the banner from the navbar items using columns.  However, since the banner is inside the navbar class, it extends the navbar too low.

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.homeBanner{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
.purpleLogo{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
.hover:hover{
    background-color: #754775;
}
.hover a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.show {
  background-color: #78496a;
    transition: none;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img id="purpleLogo" src="https://www.ogm.utah.gov/coal/images/purpleLogo.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">HOME</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a href="https://www.ogm.utah.gov/index.php">Division Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/index.php">Oil and Gas Program Home</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#mission">Mission Statement</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#responsibilities">Responsibilities</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">DATA RESEARCH CENTER</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/dataResearchCenter.php">Data Research Center Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://dataexplorer.ogm.utah.gov/">Data Explorer</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://oilgas.ogm.utah.gov/oilgasweb/live-data-search/lds-main.xhtml">LiveData Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/electronicReporting.php">Electronic Reporting</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/forms.php">FORMS</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/statistics.php">STATISTICS</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">QUICK REFERENCES</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceBonding.php">Well Bonding</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceDrillingPermits.php">Drilling Permits</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">OTHER LINKS</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=Oil%20and%20Gas%20Associations%3A">Oil and Gas Associations</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=For%20Students%20and%20Teachers">For Students and Teachers</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.naturalresources.utah.gov/">Utah DNR</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.utah.gov/main/index">Utah.gov</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/orphanWells.php">ORPHAN WELL PROGRAM</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Clicking the link goes to a Utah Oil and Gas website. They have achieved the overlapping logo using JS. If you right click on the page and choose `View Source` you can then see in the nav section that a script is inserted. The path to the script should be clickable if you want to view it :)

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode Are you referring to this script: `<script src="http://www.utah.gov/nav/fluidheader.js" type="text/javascript" class="utahgov"></script>`?  If so, I don't think this one builds the logo and places it in its location.  This is a script that's required by the state but its hidden on the page.

Comment: Maybe, there is still Header and Nav stuff included in it though. There is an image inserted directly into the navbar and the CSS for `class="purpleLogo"` says it is just on `position: absolute;` with `z-index:2000;`..... 2000 might be a bit overkill :)

Comment: I can put the script in my page and it displays a small header/navbar that they're hiding.  Its a required script by the state.  I know our team doesn't have access to the source code for this header/navbar so I don't think we would be able to change anything in it.

A 2000 z-index is odd and I already bumped it down to 2.  I think this has something to do with them using Bootstrap 3 while I'm using 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem.  There were a couple of things I had to do:

1. I ended up not needing to use the row class nor the column classes.
2. In my styles.css file, `purpleLogo` was labeled as a class when it was supposed to be an id.
3. I had to give `#navbarSupportedContent` a left margin of 224px so the navbar links didn't overlap the banner.
4. I had to give `#purpleLogo` a top position of 0px.
5. I had to remove the `.img` class and assign these properties to individual ids.

```css
#homeBanner{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
#purpleLogo{
    position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
#navbarSupportedContent {
    margin-left: 224px;
}
.hover:hover{
    background-color: #754775;
}
.hover a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
a.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.show {
  background-color: #78496a;
    transition: none;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="purpleLogo" src="https://minerals.ogm.utah.gov/images/purpleLogo.png" />
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">HOME</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li ><a href="https://www.ogm.utah.gov/index.php">Division Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/index.php">Oil and Gas Program Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#mission">Mission Statement</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#responsibilities">Responsibilities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#staff">Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#emergencies">Emergencies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#email">Email Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#facts">O&G Facts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">DATA RESEARCH CENTER</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/dataResearchCenter.php">Data Research Center Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://dataexplorer.ogm.utah.gov/">Data Explorer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://oilgas.ogm.utah.gov/oilgasweb/live-data-search/lds-main.xhtml">LiveData Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/electronicReporting.php">Electronic Reporting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/forms.php">FORMS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/statistics.php">STATISTICS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://oilgas.ogm.utah.gov/oilgasweb/live-data-search/lds-files/files-main.xhtml">WELL FILES</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="https://oilgas.ogm.utah.gov/oilgasweb/live-data-search/lds-logs/logs-main.xhtml">WELL LOGS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/noticesAndUpdates.php">NOTICES</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/rules.php">RULES AND STATUTES</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/publications.php">PUBLICATIONS</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/wellSpacingBoardOrders.php">WELL SPACING</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/mapResources.php">MAP RESOURCES</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">QUICK REFERENCES</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceBonding.php">Well Bonding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceDrillingPermits.php">Drilling Permits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceDrillingWell.php">Drilling a Well</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceOperatorChanges.php">Operator Changes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/quickReferenceReporting.php">Reporting</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">OTHER LINKS</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=Oil%20and%20Gas%20Associations%3A">Oil and Gas Associations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=For%20Students%20and%20Teachers">For Students and Teachers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=National%20Energy%20Foundation)-,Government%20Agencies,-Automated%20Geographic%20Reference">Government Agencies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=Industry%20Information%20and%20Research">Industry Information and Research</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=Oil%20and%20Gas%20Pricing">Oil and Gas Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/otherLinks.php#:~:text=Some%20of%20Utah%27s%20Top%20Oil%20and%20Gas%20Producers">Some of Utah's Top Oil and Gas Producers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.ogm.utah.gov/Board/redesign/board.html">DOGM Board Members</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.naturalresources.utah.gov/">Utah DNR</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://www.utah.gov/main/index">Utah.gov</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/orphanWells.php">ORPHAN WELL PROGRAM</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/aboutUs.php#emergencies">EMERGENCIES</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/permittingReview.php">PERMITTING</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost:1234/Utah_OG_Website/inspectionsReview.php">INSPECTIONS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<img id="homeBanner" src="https://minerals.ogm.utah.gov/images/MINERALSmainSmall.jpg"  />
```